# Rescue_from dynamic exception with inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several classes, inherited from one. And also exceptions named by that classes. To say, something like that:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base; ...; end
class Bar < Foo; ...; end
class Baz < Foo; ...; end

class Exceptions::BarError < StandardError; ...; end
class Exceptions::BazError < StantardError; ...; end
```

Now I'm writing controllers for them and controllers from `Bar` and `Baz` are totally inherited from `FoosController`. But I have one problem: I need to `rescue_from` errors having the same name as controller they are caught in. Now I have this:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from "Exceptions::#{self.controller_name[0..-2].camelcase}Error", with: :show_error

class BarsController < FoosController; end
class BazsController < FoosController; end
```

But that does not work. As I got from debug output it generates `rescue_from` only for `FooError` (which I do not even have).
It seems to be evaluated only in the parent class and nowhere in a child.

Is there something I can do?

I would also appreciate any links to docs or articles that explain the nature of this.

Comment: According to your implementation, don't you need to put it in BarsController to catch BarError?

Comment: @EJ2015 That's the way, yes. But not interesting =) I want to do it with inheritance all along, and wonder if there is any way to do this. I do not like to write the same string in every class while I can write one in parent class and do nothing more

Comment: I think the problem is that `self` is evaluated in the parent class. Would be interested to know how to make this work too.